# How can I call OS commands from within ballerina

Tags: operating-system, ballerina

I want to generate some certificates, using openSSL and provide them via REST.

I can not find a way to call my openssl in linux to generate the certificate and use it in ballerina.

no plugin found

Or is there another way to generate certificates in ballerina. There is some support for KeyStores in ballerina/crypto module
https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/crypto.html#KeyStore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will available with ballerina-1.0.0 distribution through the [ballerina/system](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/tree/master/stdlib/system/src/main/ballerina/src/system) module. The API will be look like this.

```
# Executes an operating system command as a subprocess of the current process.
#
# + command - The name of the command to be executed
# + env - Environment variables to be set to the process
# + dir - The current working directory to be set to the process
# + args - Command arguments to be passed in
# + return - Returns a `Process` object in success, or an `Error` if a failure occurs
public function exec(@untainted string command, @untainted map<string> env = {}, 
                     @untainted string? dir = (), @untainted string... args) 
                     returns Process|Error = external;
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Ballerina Swan Lake versions (2201.0.0 and higher), you can use `exec()` function provided by the `ballerina/os` module to run external commands and scripts from within your Ballerina code.

Here's a brief example:

```php
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/os;

public function main() returns error? {
    os:Process exec = check os:exec({
        value: "ls",
        arguments: ["-l"]
    });
    
    int status = check exec.waitForExit();
    io:println(string `Process exit with status: ${status}`);

    byte[] output = check exec.output(io:stdout);
    io:println(check string:fromBytes(output));
}
```

For more details you can refer to the [official documentation](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/os/latest) for the `os` module.