# Ballerina: How to call python code from inside Ballerina

Tags: python, process, ballerina

I have a ballerina backend with an http listener running. When I receive a request, want to call a python script that will take the arguments, plot a graph, and save it as png. Then returns png path to ballerina backend.

```
resource function get [string year]/[string round]/laps/[string driverName] () returns string|error {
  string graphPath = < call python code with args (year, round, driverName) >
  return graphPath
}
```

If it's not possible to directly call, please tell me how I can invoke OS command? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57558775/how-can-i-call-os-commands-from-within-ballerina) seems outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OS command execution support in Ballerina will be available with the upcoming Swanlake Update 2 release through the `os:Exec()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Ballerina OS module supports this feature starting from version 1.4.0. Following is a sample ballerina code to execute command line scripts:

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/os;

public function main() returns error? {
    os:Process exec = check os:exec({
        value: "ls",
        arguments: ["-l"]
    });
    
    int status = check exec.waitForExit();
    io:println(string `Process exit with status: ${status}`);

    byte[] output = check exec.output(io:stdout);
    io:println(check string:fromBytes(output));
}
```

See documentation : https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/os/latest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).